# Include Certain Columns of a Table

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to include only certain columns of a table when
   using org-mode's [`#+INCLUDE` directive](http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html)? You can choose certain
   rows like

```
#+INCLUDE: "./paper.org::*conclusion" :lines 1-20
```

Comment: Have you tried [remote table references](http://orgmode.org/manual/References.html)? You can have a table whose contents refer to another table even in another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Juancho's comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26577/include-certain-columns-of-a-table#comment40454_26577) was head on.

You need a table with a `#+NAME:`, which can be referenced via `'(identity remote(its-name, @@#$1))`. As an example, take

```
* test
#+NAME: src
| no | english | french | japanese |
|----+---------+--------+----------|
|  1 | one     | un     | ichi     |
|  2 | two     | deux   | ni       |
|  3 | three   | trois  | go       |
* copy
| no | french |
|----+--------|
|  1 | un     |
|  2 | deux   |
|  3 | trois  |
#+TBLFM: $1 = '(identity remote(src, @@#$1)):: $2 = '(identity remote(src, @@#$3))
```

The second table is filled by doing <kbd>C-c</kbd> on the `TBLFM`-line. It fills as many rows as the target table has.

Concerning `#+INCLUDE`: just create a secondary table that holds the needed files and include that. (using the above did not seem to work cross-file)